# Azure Migrate for VM and database

Tags: azure, azure-migrate

I am trying to use Azure Migrate to move a VM and database from Openstack based cloud to Azure as a VM and managed database. What will happen after the migration is complete ? Will Azure Migrate automatically remove the VM and the database from the source infrastructure ? Are the source resources retained as they are so that the migration can be cancelled if needed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean up the resource on Openstack on your own:

[Database - Migrate your data with Database Migration Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/design-your-migration-to-azure/5-migrate-databases)

> Migrate your data with Database Migration Service

> In the Azure portal, follow these steps to create an instance of Azure Database Migration Service, and then to run it to migrate the data in your databases:

> Create an instance of Azure Database Migration Service. Choose the pricing tier based on whether you need an online or offline migration.
> Create a new migration project. Choose the type of migration you want to perform, either offline or online.
> Specify source and target server details, including the authentication information.
> Identify the databases. Map the relevant target database on the target server to the source server.
> Run and monitor the migration.
> Select the Run migration button to start the migration. The migration activity screen will appear.
> Track the progress until the process shows as completed.
> After all the required databases are migrated, check them to make sure they're working.

> When these steps are complete, your schema and data have been migrated to the Azure SQL Database instance. You can then shut down and decommission your on-premises databases and servers.

[VM - Post-migration steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/design-your-migration-to-azure/4-migrate-servers):

> After the migration has taken place, review the security settings of the virtual machine after the migration. Restrict network access for unused services by using network security groups. Deploy Azure Disk Encryption to secure the disks from data theft and unauthorized access.

> Consider improving the resilience of the migrated machines by:

> Adding a backup schedule that uses Azure Backup.
> Replicating the machines to a secondary region using Azure Site Recovery.

> Complete clean-up tasks for the remaining on-premises servers. Such tasks may include removing the servers from local backups and removing their raw disk files from storage-area network (SAN) storage to free up space. Update documentation related to the migrated servers to reflect their new IP addresses and locations in Azure.